# How to Check regex attribute of an input after page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

There is a selectbox. and a textbox with specific pattern for Hostname.in this case when my selectbox changes the pattern of the textbox will change. my question is how can i check the selectbox value onload of the body? and check the pattern? for example if the selectbox was "Nx" at first. i would like to check the pattern . and when selectbox changes the value change.

here is my code that works only onchange of selectbox:

```js
$(function(){
  $('select[name=type]').change(function(){
    var $option = $(this).find(":selected");
    $('input[name=hostInput]').attr('pattern', $option.attr('data-pattern'));
    $('input[name=hostInput]').attr('placeholder', $option.attr('data-placeholder'));
    $('input[name=hostInput]').attr('title', $option.attr('data-title'));
  });
});
```

```css
.to_validate:invalid {
  color: navy;
  outline: none; 
  border-color: #ff1050;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <select name="type" class="minimal">
    <option value="Record" hidden>Record</option>
    <option value="NS" selected data-pattern="(?!\d+(?:\.\d+){3}$)(([a-zA-Z\d]|[a-zA-Z\d][a-zA-Z\d-]*[a-zA-Z\d])\.)*([A-Za-z\d]|[A-Za-z\d][A-Za-z\d-]*[A-Za-z\d])" data-placeholder="Hostname" data-title="Wrong host">NS</option>
    <option value="MX" data-pattern="(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])" data-placeholder="IP address" data-title="Wrong Ip Placeholder">MX </option>
  </select>
  
  <br/>
 
  <input type="text" name="hostInput" placeholder="Hostname" class="to_validate" title="Wrong host"/>
  
  
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: `$('select[name=type]').change(function(){ ... }).change();`

Comment: @Tushar what is this code?

Comment: `.change()` at the end of `change()`. This will trigger the event and event handler will be called on page load.

Comment: added but not worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding these in your javascript.

```
$(function() {
    var value= $('select[name=type]').val();
    var pattern = $('select[name=type] option:selected').data('pattern');

    $('input[name=hostInput]').attr('pattern', pattern);
    $('input[name=hostInput]').val(value);
});
```

Comment: How to pass value and pattern of check box to input box? this code that you wrote not work for this ?

Comment: excuse me , if there is another problem. for more than one row with the same field .for example one for "MX" another for "Ns" how do i use of this code?because this code will repeat the pattern for all rows .

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your new problem. You can create a new question with exactly what you are asking in detail.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery have method .ready() is called when html body elements is load and ready.. So you can check it here [link](https://api.jquery.com/ready/)

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
    var checkedVal = $( "select[name=type]" ).val();
});
```

**Update**

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
    var checkedVal = $( "select[name=type]" ).val();
    var patterns = {
    "NS":"(?!\d+(?:\.\d+){3}$)(([a-zA-Z\d]|[a-zA-Z\d][a-zA-Z\d-]*[a-zA-Z\d])\.)*([A-Za-z\d]|[A-Za-z\d][A-Za-z\d-]*[A-Za-z\d])",
    "MX":"(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])"
    }

    patterns[checkedVal].test($('input[name=hostInput]').val());//if it is true the input is valid
});
```

Comment: Is good practice to put your code on .ready(), with this  you ensure that all html elements will be available before you execute your code